# python - how to call an overriden method

Tags: python-3.x, built-in

I'm doing maintenance on a huge file that follows like this

```
...stuff

def open(account):
    ...do stuff

...stuff
```

However I need to write a str to a txt, so I was gonna do the following

```
with open(filename,"a") as file:
    file.write(mystr)
```

and this is calling the open(account) method, which is being used in a lot of classes, so renaming is not an option, how can I call the open method from the built-in functions from python and not the one with the same name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `__builtins__.open()`.